# Prove a-convex envelope coinside with given function $v$ on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

For a $v \in C(\bar\Omega)$ , $\Omega$ a bounded open set, Define the $a-$convex envelope being $$\Gamma^a_v(x) = \sup_{y,b } \{P_{-a,y,b}\mid P_{-a,y,b} \le v(x) \text{ in }\bar{\Omega}\} $$

where $P_{a,y,b} = \frac{a}{2}|x|^2 + y\cdot x + b$. Prove if $\Omega$ is strictly convex, we have $\Gamma^a_v = v$ on $\partial \Omega$.

Sorry for the question, I don't have idea to prove this.

Comment: The first idea is to set $a = 0$ and see what will hanppens

Comment: Since the bigger the $a$ is the larger the $\Gamma^a_v$ is , therefore , only needs to prove this case

Comment: while $a=0$ the envelope is just the convex hull of the epigraph, therefore it's reasonable to think they agree on the boundary.